# Cocoa Utility Class

Tags: cocoa

I think I'm missing something pretty basic here. I have a Utilities class that has some functions that are called from a few different classes. I want to be able to include Utilities.h and just say [Utilities doStuff] and have the doStuff function in Utilities.m be executed, what's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I tried using the + class method way, but now I get NSInvocation: warning: object 0x7480 of class 'Utilities' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to not make Utilities a class, unless there is some reason why you need to create instances of it. Since by nature your utility functions are a loose collection with no common theme, there's no reason to try to force an object-oriented paradigm on them. (Unlike Java, in C based languages, not everything has to be in a class.) Just define them as traditional C style functions, and call them as such.  If you really want to use the bracket notation on something that isn't an object and doesn't belong to anything that should be a class, then you can use the + notation as others have suggested.

Comment: I agree with Mr. unknown (google). Functions are part of the language. There's nothing wrong or shameful about using them if that's the functionality you want.

Answer (score 4):

The stuff that you need Utility-classes for in other languages are often in Objective-C better implemented as Categories. That is adding to the classes without creating a subclass.

Instead of having a StringUtitities-class you would create StringUtilities category for the NSString class. This is of course not true in every case but for a lot of Utility-class it is.

It's described in more detail at http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Answer (score 2):

Agree with user57368, it's implementation is probably obvious to most, but it wasn't obvious to me so I though I would create an example to show the cocoa/xcode specifics:

You need to create two files Utilities.h and Utilities.m

```
//Utilities.h 
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
   #import &lt;Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import &lt;UIKit/UIKit.h>
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
   #import &lt;Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif

float randomfloatBetween(float min, float max);

//Utilities.m
#import "Utilities.h"

float randomfloatBetween(float min, float max)
{   
   float range= max-min;
   float maxRandom = pow(2,31)-1;
   srandom((int)[NSDate date]);
   return random()/maxRandom*range + min;
}
```

Then just use #import "Utilities.h" in any source where you want to use your declared functions.

Utilities.m needs to be added to compile sources under the application target (Xcode usually does this for you).

Answer (score 1):

Import the header in the .m file that's using the utilities class, using `#import "Utilities.h`. After that, you're free to use any of its methods. Keep in mind though, that if you want to call a method on the class (instead of creating an instance of a Utilities object and calling the method on that) you need to declare it as a class method. To do this you use the + sign instead of a minus, for example `+ (void)doStuff:(NSString *)aString;`.

Apple has some pretty good documents explaining Object Oriented programming if the above example is confusing at all.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a static method in your Utilities class:

@interface Utilities

+(int) doStuff;

@end

The + sign makes the method static, as opposed to -, which is an instance method.

Comment: The Objective-C term is “class method”.